# how to create d3 Bubble Chart using internal data instead of external csv file

Tags: d3.js

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

I am using the same data as in the above mentioned example, but when I am trying to pass that data using foreach loop, It was not working fine. My input data is stored in object named data. I get the following error. Can someone please help me??? It's a request.

> csv_converter.html:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at SVGTextElement.....

```
data.forEach(function(d){
            classes=d;
d.value = +d.value;
  if (d.value) return d.value;
  var root = d3.hierarchy({children: classes})
      .sum(function(d) {if(d.value>0 && d.value!=null && d.value!=""){return d.value}})
      .each(function(d) {
        if (id = d.id) {
          var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
          d.id = id;
          d.package = id.slice(0, i);
          console.log(d.package);
          d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
        }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code a bit, and its working fine.

```
classes=data;
        data.forEach( function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
});
  var root = d3.hierarchy({children: classes})
      .sum(function(d) { if(d.value>0){return d.value}; })
      .each(function(d) {
        if (id = d.data.id) {
          var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
          d.id = id;
          d.package = id.slice(0, i);
          //console.log(d.package);
          d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
        }
      });
```